# Regular expression to check comma separted number values in Flex

Tags: regex, apache-flex, actionscript-3

Can anyone please help me to find the suitable regular expression to validate a string that has comma separated numbers, for e.g. `'1,2,3'` or `'111,234234,-09'`, etc. Anything else should be considered invalid. for e.g. `'121as23'` or `'123-123'` is invalid.

I suppose this must be possible in Flex using regular expression but I can not find the correct regular expression.

---

@Justin, I tried your suggestion `/(?=^)(?:[,^]([-+]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+))*$/` but I am facing two issues:

1. It will invalidate `'123,12'` which should be true.
2. It won't invalidate `'123,123,aasd'` which is invalid.

I tried another regex - `[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*` - which works quite well except for one issue: it validates `'12,12asd'`. I need something that will only allow numbers separated by commas.

Comment: Please avoid using such upper case attention getters in your questions.

Comment: What do you mean by "validate?" What's valid? What's not?

Comment: I think each of '1', '1,2', '2,-3', '3, 4, 5', '-1 , 3' should be considered valid.

Comment: @Ashine: I see the problem. `[,^]` was trying to match a literal `^` character. I've replaced it with `(?:,|^)` and it seems to work fine when I test it. Try the edited pattern below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example data consists of three decimal integers, each having an optional leading plus or minus sign, separated by commas with no whitespace. Assuming this describes your requirements, the Javascript/ActionScript/Flex regex is simple:

```js
var re_valid = /^[-+]?\d+(?:,[-+]?\d+){2}$/;
if (re_valid.test(data_string)) {
    // data_string is valid
} else {
    // data_string is NOT valid
}
```

However, if your data can contain any number of integers and may have whitespace the regex becomes a bit longer:

```js
var re_valid = /^[ \t]*[-+]?\d+[ \t]*(,[ \t]*[-+]?\d+[ \t]*)*$/;
```

If your data can be even more complex (i.e. the numbers may be floating point, the values may be enclosed in quotes, etc.), then you may be better off parsing the string as a CSV record and then check each value individually.

Comment: p.s. Justin's regex has several problems and does not match your test data. 1.) the '[,^]' is not correct and should be written as '(?:,|^)'. 2.) The regex matches an empty string! Also,the '(?=^)' expression does not need to be in a group - it can be written as just '^'.

Comment: I don't know how I let those slip by. Fixed them both, and it seems to test fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like what you want is this:

```
/(?!,)(?:(?:,|^)([-+]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+))*$/
```

I don't know Flex, so replace the `/` at the beginning and end with whatever's appropriate in Flex regex syntax. Your numbers will be in match set 1. Get rid of the `(?:\d*\.)?` if you only want to allow integers.

Explanation:

```
(?!,)         #Don't allow a comma at the beginning of the string.
(?:,|^)       #Your groups are going to be preceded by ',' unless they're the very first group in the string. The '(?:blah)' means we don't want to include the ',' in our match groups.
[-+]?         #Allow an optional plus or minus sign.
(?:\d*\.)?\d+ #The meat of the pattern, this matches '123', '123.456', or '.456'.
*             #Means we're matching zero or more groups. Change this to '+' if you don't want to match empty strings.
$             #Don't stop matching until you reach the end of the string.
```

Comment: There's no need to "reinforce" the caret (`^`) by putting it in a lookahead; it's an anchor no matter what comes after it (unless it's escaped with a backslash, of course).  And inside a character class (i.e., when it's enclosed in square brackets), the caret is *never* an anchor; `[,^]` matches a comma or a caret, while `[^,]` matches any character except a comma.

Comment: @Alan - Yeah, I don't know what I was thinking putting it in brackets. Also, what I meant to do was `(?!,)`, so I've edited. I had incorrectly remembered the solution to an earlier problem. Embarrassed I didn't catch those.

Comment: The "anchor-or-comma" gimmick isn't worth the effort, IMO.  Just bite the bullet and do like @ridgerunner did: match the first number separately and start repeating after that.

Comment: @Alan - Fair point. Having seen you in other regex-related questions I know you're very good with them, so I'll defer to you on this. Leaving the `(?!,)` up because it's already there and seems to work, but I'll keep it simple in the future unless I see some real benefit from it.